# Could not automate file upload to MASV portal

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, file-upload

I'm trying to upload files dynamically to my LucidLink filespace through MASV portal. I have followed the documentation for file upload in https://developer.massive.io/masv-api/upload/. Each of the steps seems to be working as expected but the final step (Finalizing the package) throws an error with errorCode 400 and errorMessage `package must have at least 1 file`.

Here's my implementation in node.js

```
const axios = require("axios");
const fs = require("fs");
const convert = require("xml-js");

(async () => {
  try {
    const { data: token_data } = await axios.post(
      `https://api.massive.app/v1/portals/${portalId}/packages`,
      {
        sender: SENDER_EMAIL,
        name: PACKAGE_NAME,
        description: "",
      },
      {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      }
    );
    const portal_access_token = token_data.access_token;
    const package_id = token_data.id;

    const packageHeaders = {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "X-Package-Token": portal_access_token,
    };

    const { data: fileToPkg } = await axios.post(
      `https://api.massive.app/v1/packages/${package_id}/files`,
      {
        kind: "file",
        name: "Person.png",
        path: "./",
        last_modified: "2023-07-25T10:59:00.000Z",
      },
      {
        headers: packageHeaders,
      }
    );

    const bluePrint = fileToPkg.create_blueprint;
    const bluePrintUrl = bluePrint.url;
    const bluePrintHeaders = bluePrint.headers;
    const bluePrintMethod = bluePrint.method;
    const fileId = fileToPkg.file.id;

    const { data: bluePrintData } = await axios.post(bluePrintUrl, null, {
      headers: bluePrintHeaders,
    });

    let result = convert.xml2json(bluePrintData, {
      compact: true,
      spaces: 4,
    });
    let jsonResult = JSON.parse(result);

    // Obtain upload urls
    const uploadId = jsonResult?.InitiateMultipartUploadResult?.UploadId._text;

    const { data: uploadUrls } = await axios.post(
      `https://api.massive.app/v1/packages/${package_id}/files/${fileId}?start=0&count=1`,
      { upload_id: uploadId },
      { headers: packageHeaders }
    );

    const { url, method } = uploadUrls[0];
    const FILE_PATH = "Person.png";

    axios({
      method,
      url,
      data: fs.readFileSync(FILE_PATH),
    })
      .then((response) => {
        axios({
          method: "POST",
          url: `https://api.massive.app/v1/packages/${package_id}/files/${fileId}/finalize`,
          headers: packageHeaders,
          data: {
            size: fs.statSync(FILE_PATH).size,
            file_extras: { upload_id: uploadId },
            chunk_extras: [
              {
                partNumber: "1",
                etag: response.headers.etag,
              },
            ],
          },
        })
          .then((response) => {
            console.log("response", response.status);
          })
          .catch((error) => console.error(error.message));
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error.message, error.response.data);
      });

    const { data: packageFinalData } = await axios.post(
      `https://api.massive.app/v1/packages/${package_id}/finalize`,
      {},
      {
        headers: packageHeaders,
      }
    );

  } catch (error) {
    console.log("error", error.message, error.response?.data);
  }
})();
```

From my debugging, it's obvious that the error is thrown in the last axios request.

```
const { data: packageFinalData } = await axios.post(
      `https://api.massive.app/v1/packages/${package_id}/finalize`,
      {},
      {
        headers: packageHeaders,
      }
    );
```

I'm obviously adding a file `Person.png` to the package, I'm not sure of what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to figure out the issue. The finalize package process has to occur after the finalize file process is completed and not before. With the current set up (Due to the nested dot then structure), it occurs before and not after.
So, one solution would be to move the finalize package code in the finalize file then block. Or use async await.